# Connect multiple database in mongoDb using Nodejs runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect the multiple database with the API request. I tried to connect the DB using this code:

```
const connectionString = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_HOST}/${company.dbName}`;

      const client = new MongoClient(connectionString, {
        autoReconnect: true,
        reconnectTries: 60,
        reconnectInterval: 10000,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.DB_USER,
          password: process.env.DB_PASS
        }
      });

      await client.connect();
      await client.db(company.dbName);
```

I didn't achieve any solution with the mentioned code.

Looking for the good solution :)